# Verifying method invocation in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm trying to test a Grails controller that should call a method on a domain class. Here's a sample of how my setup looks like:

Domain class:

```
class Vampire {

  def turnIntoBat() { ... }

}
```

Controller:

```
class VampireController {

  def transform(Vampire vampire) {
    ...
    vampire.turnIntoBat()
    ...
  }

}
```

Test:

```
void "Bat transformation"() {
  when:
  controller.request.json = new Vampire(...)
  controller.transform()

  then:
  //verify that turnIntoBat is invoked
  ...
}
```

As can be seen in this test, I'm sending the data using JSON, so mocking the domain class wouldn't make any difference (in the context of what I'm trying to do). Alternatively, I could just call `controller.transform(mockVampire)` but I'd like to stick to that one above as much as possible since I'm also trying to test JSON/REST aspect of the controller.

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Comment: It didn't really answer my question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here You have the whole test (with mocked grails classes):

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {

    void "test bat transformation"() {
      given:
      def controller = new VampireController()
      def vampire = GroovyMock(Vampire)

      when:
      controller.transform(vampire)

      then:
      1 * vampire.turnIntoBat()
    }   
}

class Vampire {
  def turnIntoBat() { }
}

class VampireController {
  def transform(Vampire vampire) {
    vampire.turnIntoBat()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but like I said in my question, I'm quite aware I could do it this way. I'm just looking for a way to make it work while sticking with the JSON body approach.

Comment: No idea how to do it. I'm not a grails developer. Maybe @JeffScottBrown may help You.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that Grails is creating the `Vampire` command object that gets passed to the action. We can't easily spy on it.

We can use some meta programming like this:

```
class Vampire {
    def turnIntoBat () {
        [bat:true]
    }
}


@TestFor(FooController)
@Mock([Vampire])
class FooControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def "transforms vampire into bat manual meta programming" () {
        given:
        MetaMethod org = Vampire.metaClass.getMetaMethod('turnIntoBat')
        boolean calledTurnIntoBat = false
        Vampire.metaClass.turnIntoBat = { ->
            calledTurnIntoBat = true
            org.invoke delegate
        }

        request.method = 'POST'
        request.json = new Vampire()

        when:
        controller.transform()

        then:
        calledTurnIntoBat
        response.json.bat
    }
}
```

It is a bit ugly/noisy but it works.. :)

The spock documentation talks about a `GroovySpy` that sounds like a simpler solution. We can pass a `global:true` that makes spock intercept the calls on any object of the given class.

It should be possible to do something like the code below but I don't get it running (grails 2.4.2).

```
@Ignore
def "transforms vampire into bat with GroovySpy" () {
    given:
    def anyVampire = GroovySpy (Vampire, global:true)

    request.method = 'POST'
    request.json = new Vampire()


    when:
    controller.transform()

    then:
    1 * anyVampire.turnIntoBat ()
    response.json.bat
}
```

Comment: I tried the second suggestion but it doesn't work. It says there's too few invocation on the spy/mock. The first suggestion is a little to verbose/tedious though.

Comment: Right, as I said, this does not work ;-) Probably better to write an extra test with a Mock for the method call. Not sure that's worth it though. Putting json in, getting json out should be good enough.

Comment: `GroovyMock` works though, but it effectively disables GORM in tests (which is how I do the test right now).